# JQuery AJAX Success With Multiple MVC Controller Methods

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

Let's say I post a form to an MVC controller and action like this

```
function ajaxFunction() {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ControllerName/FirstMethod",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            //I'm wondering if this gets run after the FirstMethod or SecondMethod   
        }
    });
)
```

The controller action does something, then redirects to the next method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FirstMethod()
{
    //Some code run here

    //Send to the next method
    return RedirectToAction("SecondMethod");
}

public void SecondMethod()
{
    //Something else done here
}
```

So the whole process is to post to the FirstMethod, then run the SecondMethod.  My question is - when does the Ajax success() method run?  Is it after the FirstMethod or SecondMethod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RedirectToAction returns a HTTP status code of 302, which makes AJAX do a GET to the redirect URL (SecondMethod).

jQuery AJAX success only gets called when a 2XX HTTP code is returned. If SecondMethod returns something with a 2XX status code (such as a View), it will be then. Otherwise, it will never be called.

Comment: That's very interesting.  Thanks for the response.  What happens when you call a public void method directly though?  I have a few of those in my code and I'm using the ajax success function.  Is that a different scenario?

Comment: When redirectied to an action method that returns void, MVC actually returns an EmptyResult which is a 200 status code so it would indeed run the success() callback. Otherwise it depends on the ActionResult type. Most return a 2XX code except HttpNotFoundResult, HttpUnauthorizedResult, HttpStatusCodeResult.